# Comment with Latex commands.

Tags: adobe

I'm searching a way to comment my pdf files with Latex commands. Is there a way to do that? I use Adobe Reader X to open my pdf files.

Comment: Have a look at the pdfcomment package.

Comment: Welcome! It is not clear exactly what you want to do. Do you want to create a PDF with notes or annotations containing commands which will be visible when opened in acroread? Or are you asking how to add annotations to the PDF within acroread?

Comment: I want to add comment in pdf files, when I'm read the text in Adobe Reader, containing Latex format (equations, etc).

Comment: Todonotes places to do notes in the margins.  Do you want that, or sticky like notes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesterday i met a great package to comment a pdf, especially for todo notes but also great for other comments. In color. It is called `todonotes` and has a great documentation.

[Here it is on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes)

[And here is the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf)

In my opinion it is great for collaborative writing.

O, i see. Someone was faster

Comment: your suggestion it will be really helpful when I write some text. But what I want is, when I read a pdf file, that I don't have the original latex, make annotation with using latex functions in Adobe Reader, or similar.
Thinking better about it, maybe it's more efficient produce an annotation with Latex  and then attach this in Pdf file.

Comment: Maybe there is a solution with pdfpages, but maybe there is a much better solution. And i think this is not a job for LaTeX, is it?